React Form Submission Logs Updated Data but Does Not Update Database or Navigate to Tasks Page
now i 'm creating endpoint for editing task for  to do app  using laravel and react.js
the end point i tested it using postman and it returns success response http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/4
and the body is
 {
    "user_id": 1,
    "title": "Updated Task4",
    "description": "Updated description",
    "status": "completed",
    "due_date": "2024-08-01",
    "category_id": 1
}


and here's the response
{
    "data": {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 1,
        "title": "Updated Task4",
        "description": "Updated description",
        "status": "completed",
        "due_date": "2024-08-01",
        "category_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2024-07-23T21:12:40.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2024-07-25T00:00:22.000000Z"
    }
}

 by creating edit-task component in react and implement this code in it 

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'; 
import { useParams, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import Joi from 'joi';

export default function EditTask() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [task, setTask] = useState({
    user_id: '', // Initially empty
    title: '',
    description: '',
    status: 'pending',
    due_date: '',
    category_id: ''
  });
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
    fetchTask();
  }, []);

  const fetchCategories = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/categories');
      setCategories(response.data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching categories:', error);
    }
  };

  const fetchTask = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/${id}`);
      setTask(response.data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching task:', error);
    }
  };

  const schema = Joi.object({
    user_id: Joi.number().required(),
    title: Joi.string().min(3).max(255).required(),
    description: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).allow(''),
    status: Joi.string().valid('pending', 'completed').required(),
    due_date: Joi.date().allow(''),
    category_id: Joi.number().required()
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setTask(prevTask => ({
      ...prevTask,
      [name]: value
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form submitted'); // Debug log
    console.log('Task data before submission:', task); // Log task data

    const { error } = schema.validate(task, { abortEarly: false });
    if (error) {
      const validationErrors = {};
      error.details.forEach(detail => {
        validationErrors[detail.path[0]] = detail.message;
      });
      setErrors(validationErrors);
      return;
    }

    setErrors({});
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await axios.put(`http://localhost:8000/api/tasks/${id}`, task, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });

      console.log('Response from server:', response); // Debug log
      console.log('Updated task data:', response.data); // Debug log

      if (response.status === 200) {
        navigate('/tasks');
      } else {
        setErrors({ form: 'Failed to update task. Please try again.' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating task:', error);
      setErrors({ form: 'Failed to update task. Please check the form data.' });
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <title>Edit Task</title>
      </Helmet>
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <h1>Edit Task</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="title" className="form-label">Title</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              id="title"
              name="title"
              value={task.title}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Enter task title"
              required
            />
            {errors.title && <small className="text-danger">{errors.title}</small>}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="description" className="form-label">Description</label>
            <textarea
              className="form-control"
              id="description"
              name="description"
              value={task.description}
              onChange={handleChange}
              placeholder="Enter task description"
            />
            {errors.description && <small className="text-danger">{errors.description}</small>}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="status" className="form-label">Status</label>
            <select
              className="form-select"
              id="status"
              name="status"
              value={task.status}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            >
              <option value="pending">Pending</option>
              <option value="completed">Completed</option>
            </select>
            {errors.status && <small className="text-danger">{errors.status}</small>}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="due_date" className="form-label">Due Date</label>
            <input
              type="date"
              className="form-control"
              id="due_date"
              name="due_date"
              value={task.due_date}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            {errors.due_date && <small className="text-danger">{errors.due_date}</small>}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="category_id" className="form-label">Category</label>
            <select
              className="form-select"
              id="category_id"
              name="category_id"
              value={task.category_id}
              onChange={handleChange}
              required
            >
              <option value="">Select a category</option>
              {categories.map(cat => (
                <option key={cat.id} value={cat.id}>{cat.name}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
            {errors.category_id && <small className="text-danger">{errors.category_id}</small>}
          </div>
          {errors.form && <div className="alert alert-danger">{errors.form}</div>}
          <button type="submit" className="btn invadebtn" disabled={loading}>
            {loading ? <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> : 'Update Task'}
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


it doesn't work it logs in the console the updated data but neither it updated in the database or navigate me to tasks page
to update the database && and navigate me to tasks page

Database update would be handled on the server side, but you have not shared that code with us. Too much code shared on the client side.
